# Is text-anchor overriding the value of x?

Tags: css, svg

I was just going through the documentation of MDN **[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor)** on the attribute of text anchor, And there is this great example as following:

```
        <!-- Materialisation of anchors -->
        <path d="M60,15 L60,110 M30,40 L90,40 M30,75 L90,75 M30,110 L90,110" stroke="grey" />


        <!-- Anchors in action -->
        <text text-anchor="start"
              x="60" y="40">A</text>

        <text text-anchor="middle"
              x="60" y="75">A</text>

        <text text-anchor="end"
              x="60" y="110">A</text>

        <!-- Materialisation of anchors -->
        <circle cx="60" cy="40" r="3" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="60" cy="75" r="3" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="60" cy="110" r="3" fill="red" />

    <style><![CDATA[
    text{
        font: bold 36px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    ]]></style>
    </svg>
```

The above example really does show us how that attribute can be used **[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wynhn1ds/)**  , My question is, the attribute, `x` already gives the text element a specific positioning on the `x` axis, so is `text-anchor` really overriding the value of `x` ? Well that's my only question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `text-anchor` doesn't override the `x` attribute, it *complements* it by saying whether or not the location given by `x` and `y` is actually the lower left, lower middle or lower right corner ot the text to be positioned.